# How to get raw SMS bytes on Android?

Tags: android, sms, gsm

I know how to retrieve SMS in Android, I get plenty of details such as `sender`, `date`, `thread_id` etc. However, I would like to get raw GSM message (in form of byte array e.g.), that is received by the device.

Is that possible? How to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SmsMessage.GetPdu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getPdu()), which returns a byte array.

The key term to look for is "PDU" = Protocol Data Unit, i.e. the contents of the SMS protocol message that is created when an SMS is sent or received over the network.